# Manually creating Solr CursorMark in client

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, codec

I understand that Solr will generate and return nextCursorMark when querying. However, due to how my client filters and paginates, I want to be able to create a cursor pointing to an arbitrary document.

It seems like this is doable by referencing/using [CursorMark](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/04ba04c29d5079d74231aa5a54d5f0a93bd16f2b/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/CursorMark.java#L239) and [JavaBinCodec](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/6d5b1ae7f4bf02f8d0a4a193af08d0ec0cd0b0aa/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/common/util/JavaBinCodec.java#L75) and providing the values of the sorted columns.

However, given that these classes are not shipped in any artifact AFAICT (like [SolrJ](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/solr/solrj)) it feels hacky. I would also be concerned that Solr might expect the codec to only be used internally so perhaps make non-backwards-compatible changes at unexpected intervals (though I guess this would be sniffed out when testing in lower environments if we upgrade Solr version).

Has anyone done this before. Any other concerns?

EDIT: Just noticed that JavaBinCodec IS shipped with SolrJ, so that reduces the hackiness.